# Why doesn't VB6 image combo show images in Win 7

Tags: windows, vb6, controls

Unfortunately I need to make changes to an old VB6 application.  I have noticed that the image combo from mscomctl.ocx does not work correctly in Windows 7.  No images are displayed, even though it is linked to an imagelist control, and worked fine in XP.

Does anyone know why this might have broken in Win 7 and suggest a fix?

Comment: Well, I have just tried this in the IDE, and it works fine. You will have to create a simple repro case and show us it.

Comment: Please go to Event Viewer, click Applications and see if any error is logged.

Comment: 32 bit OS.  How do I upload a file here?

Comment: Uploaded sample proj to https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=3C0B4480E8FB2850&id=3C0B4480E8FB2850!142

Comment: Sorry, that URI didn't work. In any case, surely you can post code here. It doesn't have to be complicated - just a simple repro case. All I did was to load up an image list with 16x16 bitmaps in design time, and then call ImageControl.ComboItems.Add() a couple of times in an event procedure.

Comment: Haha - the ComboItems.Add was the bit I was missing! I haven't done this stuff in years and thought you just assigned the imageList and magic happened.  I think the original code stopped working properly because of some binary compatibility issue - and I forgot about all that good stuff years ago too.  Seems this is a non-issue now - but thanks for your time.

Comment: Automatically adding items via telepathy? Never thought that would work!

Comment: So is the answer that there is no Win7 issue at all, just a programming error that would fail the same way on any version of Windows?

Comment: I assumed that this was a variation on a bug I had seen where the binary image list information added using the designer just got magically "lost" when reloading the project. That's why I never store the images with the form/usercontrol, and instead load the bitmaps from resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assigning the image list to the combo is not enough!  One needs to add the items too:

```
ImageCombo1.ComboItems.Add 1, "key1", "text1", 1
ImageCombo1.ComboItems.Add 2, "key2", "text2", 2
```

And then you have to remember what binary compatibility is when deploying. Gosh, the progress we've made since VB6...  long live .Net.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the following worked for me where ImageCombo was my ImageCombo box, and ImageList was my Image List control!

```
Private Sub Command_Click()

    Set ImageCombo.ImageList = ImageList

    With ImageCombo.ComboItems
        .Add , "OPEN_FOLDER", "Open Folder", "IMG_OPEN_FOLDER"
        .Add , "CLOSED_FOLDER", "Closed Folder", "IMG_CLOSED_FOLDER"
        .Add , "NEW_DOCUMENT", "New Document", "IMG_NEW_DOCUMENT"
        .Add , "PLUS", "Plus", "IMG_PLUS"
        .Add , "MINUS", "Minus", "IMG_MINUS"
    End With

End Sub
```

IMG_xxxx are my image list keys.

Answer (score 1):

MSCOMCTL.OCX

6.1.97.82 Works
6.1.98.33 Doesn't work

It's da' version

try with 6.1.97.82

---

I Got it!

In version 6.1.98.33, when you add items to comboitems collection, you have to set the third parameter ("Text"). Then the image will be shown. You can set an empty string "".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps MSCOMCTL.OCX isn’t correctly registered or that it isn’t compatible with your Windows. Please open a Command Prompt and run as Administrator, then type the following command:

```
Regsvr32 MSCOMCTL.OCX
```

If the issue still persists, download a new MSCOMCTL.OCX and register it again. You can download the MSCOMCTL.OCX from the following link:
[Mscomctl.zip](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/mscomctl.zip)

Comment: Yes, I did actually have to re-register a whole bunch of DLLs and OCXs as they looked a bit corrupt in regedit.  Works now that I've remembered how to add items to the list...  Thanks!